# Bootstrap carousel reveal part of next slide, how do I remove the hidden part?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I've set up a Bootstrap carousel which shows two slides and then a part of the third slide. If you look at the CodePen I have put a border around the entire carousel and you can see the white-space that needs removing so the carousel can occupy the full width of the page. I want to keep the third item in the carousel only showing a small portion (e.g. a third) but remove the whitespace to the right of it (between the border and the button/third tile) so I can align the carousel with the edges of the page.

I suspect the answer lies with overflow: hidden; but I cannot get it to work. Any help would be much appreciated. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dhedley/pen/KKzXjXw?editors=1100)

**EDIT**

I never managed to fix the issue in bootstrap. However I did redesign it using slick as can be seen here: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/dhedley/pen/abNjvzq). If anyone is wanting to achieve the same effect I would recommend Owl Carousel or Slick. They both scale better too :)

```
<div class="container" style="display: inline-block; float: right; width:100%">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 center-block" style="padding-left:0">
              <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                  <div class="carousel-inner">


                      <div class="item active">
                          <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1">
                            <div class="content_wrapper">
                              <div class="panel_wrapper">
                                <img src="https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=14IIfkms_-_agwa-cV1YZpZ3KSZfSXF7a&export=download" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class = 'panel'></div>
                              </div>
                              <img src="https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1ZvOZQngzmo8v-a3wk1jTCrt-h9Lq2fqH&export=download" class="img-logo">
                              <div class = "text_wrapper">
                                <h4>Pharmaceuticals</h4>
                                <div class='line'></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </a></div>
                      </div>


                      <div class="item">
                          <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1">
                            <div class="content_wrapper">
                              <div class="panel_wrapper">
                                <img src="https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1NkiQw07YRxnYhhVFsZ19ygkfGh7CDbqo&export=download" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class = 'panel'></div>
                              </div>
                              <img src="https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1ZvOZQngzmo8v-a3wk1jTCrt-h9Lq2fqH&export=download" class="img-logo">
                              <div class = "text_wrapper">
                                <h4>Toiletries & Cosmetics</h4>
                                <div class='line'></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </a></div>
                      </div>


                      <div class="item">
                          <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1">
                            <div class="content_wrapper">

                              <div class="panel_wrapper">
                                <img src="https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1UAIMYCqWqXCuNiauvGLlGhB-eqk0j2pu&export=download" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class = 'panel'></div>
                              </div>
                              <img src="https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1ZvOZQngzmo8v-a3wk1jTCrt-h9Lq2fqH&export=download" class="img-logo">
                              <div class = "text_wrapper">
                                <h4>Food & Drink</h4>
                                <div class='line'></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </a></div>
                      </div>


                       <div class="item">
                          <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1">
                            <div class="content_wrapper">
                              <div class="panel_wrapper">
                                <img src="https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=14IIfkms_-_agwa-cV1YZpZ3KSZfSXF7a&export=download" class="img-responsive">
                                <div class = 'panel'></div>
                              </div>
                              <img src="https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1ZvOZQngzmo8v-a3wk1jTCrt-h9Lq2fqH&export=download" class="img-logo">
                              <div class = "text_wrapper">
                                <h4>placeholder</h4>
                                <div class='line'></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </a></div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="my-right-button">
                    <div class="greyout"></div>
                    <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" class="carousel_button right">
                      <img src="https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1C97zsCJHIRSOTsl5JSkDfw3IZEBjDYfz&export=download" class='myButton'> 
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.carousel.slide{
  border-style: solid;
}
/* css for custom slide animation, makes every tile just slide one position left*/
.carousel{
  .carousel-inner{
    > .item{
      transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
    }
    .active{
      &.left{
        left:-33%;
      }
      &.right{
        left:33%;
      }
    }
    .next{
      left: 33%;
    }
    .prev{
      left: -33%;
    }
    
    @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
      > .item{
        // use your favourite prefixer here
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out all;
        backface-visibility: visible;
        transform: none!important;
      }
    }
  }
}



/* css for default slide animation
.carousel,
.carousel-inner,
.carousel-inner > .item {
    overflow: hidden;
}
*/



.carousel-inner:before {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.carousel-inner:after {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    left: 82%; /*determines how much of the right tile is shown*/
    content:"";
    display:block;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.carousel-control{
  opacity: 1;
}
/* left carousel button*/
.carousel-control.left{
  background: initial;
}

/* right carousel button*/
.carousel-control.right{
  background: none;
  width: 15%; /* fits to width of third tile*/
  color: #000;
  top: -10px;
  right:18%; /* positions relative to third tile*/
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-image: none;
}
.my-right-button{
  position:absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0%;
  left: auto;
  width: 14%; /* fits to width of third tile*/
  height: 100%;
  right:18%; /* positions relative to third tile*/
}

.greyout{
  position: absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel_button{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.myButton{
   max-width: 70%;
   height: auto;
   width: auto; /* ie8 */
}
/*tile background image*/
.img-responsive{
}

/*smaller image scales with screen size
positioned relative to background image (bottom left)*/
.img-logo{
  position:absolute;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 3%;
  height: auto;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 20%;
}

/*wraps the two images together*/
.img_wrapper{
  position: relative;
}

/*caption text*/
.item h4{
  font-size: 1.5vw;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 15px;
  font-family: Museo sans rounded;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* underline underneath caption*/
.line{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 20%;
}

/* remove the underline for any links*/
.col-xs-4 a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* panel is a div which wraps itself to the background image
it displays itself on top of the image. It contains a background
colour with an opacity so on hover the panel is displayed, it gives effect
that the image is changing colour.

By default the background colour has 100% opacity (it cannot be seen)
On hover it transitions to a different colour/opacity. This gives the fading
in and out effect
*/
.panel{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(26,165,210,0);
}

/* used to wrap the panel to the image*/
.panel_wrapper{
  position: relative;
}

/* wraps the all the content in the tile, adds a background colour
so the hover effect appiles to the caption as well
*/
.content_wrapper{
  background-color: none;
}

.button_wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  height:100%;
}


/*all below code adds hover transition to tiles*/

.content_wrapper:hover{
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background-color: rgba(26,165,210,0.9);
}

.content_wrapper:hover .panel{
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  background-color: rgba(26,165,210,0.9);
}

.content_wrapper:hover .line{
  border-color: white;
}

.content_wrapper:hover h4{
  color:white;
}
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   
   
   // does not scroll through automatically
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: false
    })
   
   // go through each carousel item and append the next two to it
    $('.carousel .item').each(function () {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        if (next.next().length > 0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        } else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `.carousel-inner:after` style (maybe just add `display:none` if it's default style or adapt the style) and then put `.my-right-button` at `right:0;`

That's what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's not what I wanted though. I'll try to phrase it better, I want to keep the third tile only showing a small portion (e.g. a third) but remove the whitespace to the right of it, so the carousel in its current state can occupy the full page width. At the moment it doesn't occupy the full width because of the fact the not visible part of the third tile still exists.